# Controls available on WPF tab are not getting displayed

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpftoolkit

I am new to WPF and facing some wierd issue. I have designed a screen having a tab control. Tab control has two tabs and each tab item has few controls on it. 
The issue is; When I open same solution from different machine I am not able to navigate between these two tabs in design time but on machine (on which I have designed screen) it works perfectly fine and allows me to view controls on both tabs.

So my question is; do I need to explicitely intall any plug-in to view the controls available on tab controls or is there any setting needs to be done for same.

Answer (score 0):

Only an idea: Check the .net framework-versions of the different machines. Maybe you use a control that is not available with the installed framework version. For example if you have on your machine 3.5Sp1 and on the other machines only 3.5. This can lead to such effects.

Comment: Thanks for comments HCL. I have checked .Net framework versions on both machines and observed both are same i.e. 3.5 SP1.